# XSL. Display data in two or more columns side by side

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I have the following XSL, XML and CSS:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
      <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

      <!-- Indentation. HTML output beautifier-->
      <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
      <xsl:template match="/">
           <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="/">
           <html>
                <head>
                     <title><xsl:value-of select="doc/page/name"/></title>
                     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
                </head>
                <body>
                     <xsl:for-each select="doc/item">
                          <div class="item">
                                <xsl:apply-templates/>
                          </div>
                     </xsl:for-each>
                </body>
          </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- XML <value> -->
    <xsl:template match="doc/item/section/row">
         <p>
              <xsl:for-each select="value">
                   <xsl:value-of select="."/><br />
              </xsl:for-each>
         </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- XML <section name> -->
    <xsl:template match="doc/item/section/name">
          <p><strong><xsl:value-of select="."/></strong></p>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- XML <item name> -->
    <xsl:template match="doc/item/name">
         <p><strong><xsl:value-of select="."/></strong></p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doc>
     <page>
          <name>GoPro</name>
     </page>
     <item>
          <name>GoPro Hero 4 Black</name>  
          <section>
               <name>Video resolution</name>
               <row>
                    <value>4K</value>
                    <value>30, 25, 24</value>
                    <value>Ultra wide</value>
                    <value>3840x2160</value>
                    <note></note>
               </row>
               <row>
                    <value>4K Superview</value>
                    <value>24</value>
                    <value>Ultra wide</value>
                    <value>3840x2160</value>
                    <note></note>
               </row>
               <row>
                    <value>WVGA</value>
                    <value>240</value>
                    <value>Ultra wide</value>
                    <value>848x480</value>
                    <note></note>
               </row>
          </section>
          <section>
               <name>Video format</name>
               <row>    
                    <value>H.264 codec, .MP4 file format</value>
                    <note></note>
               </row>
          </section>
          <section>
               <name>Weight</name>
               <row>    
                    <value>88g (3.1oz)</value>
                    <value>With housing: 152g (5.4oz)</value>
                    <note></note>
               </row>
          </section>
     </item>
     <item>
          <name>GoPro Hero 4 Silver</name>
          <section>
               <name>Video resolution</name>
               <row>
                    <value>4K</value>
                    <value>15, 12.5</value>
                    <value>Ultra wide</value>
                    <value>3840x2160</value>
                    <note></note>
               </row>
               <row>
                    <value>-</value>
                    <value>-</value>
                    <value>-</value>
                    <value>-</value>
                    <note></note>
               </row>
               <row>
                    <value>WVGA</value>
                    <value>240</value>
                    <value>Ultra wide</value>
                    <value>848x480</value>
                    <note></note>
               </row>
          </section>
          <section>
               <name>Video format</name>
               <row>
                    <value>H.264 codec, .MP4 file format</value>
                    <note></note>
               </row>
          </section>
          <section>
                <name>Weight</name>
                <row>
                     <value>83g (oz)</value>
                     <value>With housing: 147g (oz)</value>
                     <note></note>
                </row>
          </section>
     </item>
 </doc>
```

CSS:

```
 .item {
      width: 250px;
      float: left;
 }
```

The output is correctly displayed on two columns side by side thanks to the CSS .item class.

But now I would like to **achieve the following result:**

```
                   | GoPro 3 Black    | GoPro 3 Silver
----------------------------------------------------------
| Video resolution | 4K               | 4K               |
|                  | 30, 25, 24       | 15, 12.5         |
|                  | Ultra wide       | Ultra wide       |
|                  | ...              | ...              |
|                  |                  |                  |
| Video format     | H.264            | H.264            |
|                  | ...              | ...              |
|                  |                  |                  |
```

**Where *video resolution, video format, weight* are on the left most column** and **correctly vertically spaced** to be at the right height of the corresponding value.

As I just started to learn XSL, I would like to know is this can be done with XSL or I have to work it out with CSS.

I prefer **NOT to use HTML TABLE** as afterwords I would like to use some javascript effects to hide and show the columns which I would keep inside DIVs.

Comment: XSL is for tranformation/translation (of XML into HTML in this example). CSS is for 'Styling'. The two cannot really be used "instead of the other".

Comment: "*I would like to know is this can be done with XSL*" What exactly is *this*? Show us the **HTML code** you want to achieve - and explain the **rules** for producing it from the input.

Comment: @Michael "this" is the table I draw below my request "I would like to achieve the following result:".

Comment: A drawing is not code.

Comment: The XSL+XML above produce the HTML code. If I could produce the HTML code I wish to, I would'nt have posted a question here.

Comment: I am afraid you have lost me. If the XSL+XML above produce the HTML code you want, then what is your question? If they don't, then you must show us the HTML code that you do want. If you are not sure what HTML code you want, then your question is not about XSLT.

Comment: Why don't you just print them out in 3 lists and then align them with CSS? Edit: You know that XSLT is not an alternative to CSS right? XSLT transforms mostly data, CSS mostly design

Comment: It was a simple innocent question :-(

Comment: @Nicero No one is attacking you, there's no need to become defensive. It's just that it's not at all clear what you're asking. This is a coding forum; we can help you write code that produces a known result. Your result is not known at this point.

Comment: I think using an HTML table is the easiest way to try to align your columns/rows (that's what a table is for).  If you want to hide certain columns using javascript, just assign all the cells in that column a certain CSS class, and then hide all elements of that class.

Comment: Perhaps you were misled by the fact that XSLT code is usually called a "stylesheet"? But XSLT is really about transforming XML - not about styling and displaying content. A styling language in the XML world is XSL-FO.